# change the 'contrast' of a numpy array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let `x` be a `numpy` array, which is an m x n matrix, with values in the interval [0,1]. I wish to

> *enlarge entries which are bigger than nearby entries* and *decrease entries which are smaller than nearby entries*.

Essentially, increase the contrast, but still keep the values inside [0,1]

Here, 'nearby' entries of `x[i,j]` are `x[u,v]` for `i-r<u<i+r, j-r<v<j+r`, where `r` is some input parameter. Is there a function or package that achieves this?

P.S. The background of this problem is that I have the values of a KDE function that measures the density of marine traffic and I'm trying to determine 'highways' of ships (so if a ship is not near a highway, it is suspicious). But on lakes, the traffic is smaller than near the ocean coast. I wish to even this out, to be able to determine highways on lakes and in the ocean.

Comment: You are describing something very similar to *"Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization"*, i.e. CLAHE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization It is in scikit-image https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist and OpenCV https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html

Comment: Try „convolving“ it with an appropriate kernel. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html

Comment: What do you want to do with entries that are the same? That is, do you want edge detection, or to shift constant regions? Eg, with a step, `[.2, .2, .2., .6, .6, .6]` do you want `[.2, .2, .1, .7, .6, .6]` or `[.1, .1, .1, .7, .7, .7]`?

Comment: @tom10 I don't understand. My x is 2D, if an entry has the same value as its nearby entries, then it shouldn't change (much). Of course my question is vague. I will know if the method is successful when my lake highways are of similar brightness as ocean highways. For this, an appropriate value of the neighbourhood parameter r should be picked, and some sensible transformation, like x[i,j] = x[i,j] / meanValue(neighbourhood of x[i,j]).

Comment: @MarkSetchell, AlexNe Thank you! Give me a few days to try it out. Hopefully, this can be applied to a numpy matrix and gives back a numpy matrix.

Comment: Your definition of "enlarge entries which are bigger than nearby entries and decrease entries which are smaller than nearby entries"  immediately makes me think of Laplacian kernels.